# How to trim and replace in one regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm writing a sublime text snippet,

I want to insert a string which removes the header and tailer of the file path and replace the slashes with dots.

e.g.

input: `'/workspace/proto/src/app/dashboard/scrum/burnDownChart.js'`

output: `'dashboard.scrum.burnDownChart'`

The depth of the file is unknown.

I have written `${TM_FILEPATH/^.*app\/(.*)\.js$/\1/}` to remove the header and tailer

And I have written `${TM_FILEPATH/\//./g}'` to replace the slash

But I cannot find a way to chain the operations or to nest one in another

I've tried `${${TM_FILEPATH/^.*app\/(.*)\.js/\1/}/\//\./g}` , but it simply gives `/\//\./g}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Macro to chain a couple of commands like the ones you described together.
[check them out here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html)